# Identifying the date format in the client's machine

Tags: javascript, date-format

I have a requirement in my project to show a date in the client machine format. I am aware of the property in javascript **window.navigator.userLanguage** or **window.navigator.language**.. But it is only returning the language of the client machine like 'en-US', 'en-GB' etc.

If the user customizes the date format of the machine for eg:-dd-MMM-yyyy, is there any way to get that format in Javascript?

Thanks in advance

suhaib

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. The system exposes to JavaScript the underlying date/time, in its internal format, not the format the user may have chosen as a preference. Also, determining language/locale is problematic cross-browser. Opera, for examples, exposes the `en` (English) flag no fewer than 3 times in the various properties of the `navigator` object, but not once `en-GB`.

Comment: Thanks for the info. do you have any alternate method to suggest? in Asp.net?

Comment: Server-side languages derive time from the server, not the client's machine, so I wouldn't have thought this was a great avenue for you either. Server-side languages do (if the browser allows) have access to various headers sent by the browser (browser name, version etc) but this wouldn't give you any different information (I would presume) from what you get in the `navigator` object.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`.toLocaleDateString()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString):

```
var yourDate = new Date();
alert(yourDate.toLocaleDateString());
```

This doesn't tell your code what the user's selected date format is, but it lets you display a date in whatever the user's format is.

On my PC the above alerts "Tuesday, 26 June 2012".

The [`.toLocaleTimeString()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString) does the equivalent thing for the time.

The [`.toLocaleString()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) displays date *and* time.

Comment: But these methods wont work if the user customizes his machine's date format. It will still return the old value..

Comment: It will, after browser restart.